# Asset_Sync not pushing to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3

I am building a rails app on heroku, and want to deploy the js, css, and image files to a bucket on Amazon. I haven't found many resources for this, but I am using this (2012) tutorial for guidance; https://firmhouse.com/blog/complete-guide-to-serving-your-rails-assets-over-s3-with-asset_sync

The site is mainly css and js at the moment. Here is my code so far;

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do

config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localize.s3.amazonaws.com"

config.cache_classes = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.serve_static_assets = false

config.assets.compress = true

config.assets.compile = false

config.assets.digest = true

end
```

**initializers/asset_sync.rb**

```
 if defined?(AssetSync)
 AssetSync.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = ENV['FOG_PROVIDER']
  config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] 
  config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
  config.fog_region = ENV['FOG_REGION']

 # Don't delete files from the store
 config.existing_remote_files = "delete"

 # Automatically replace files with their equivalent gzip compressed version
 config.gzip_compression = true

# Use the Rails generated 'manifest.yml' file to produce the list of files to
# upload instead of searching the assets directory.
config.manifest = true

config.custom_headers = { '.*' => { cache_control: 'max-age=31536000', expires: 1.year.from_now.httpdate } }
 end
end
```

**Heroku Vars**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:            *****************
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:        *****************************
FOG_DIRECTORY:                localize
FOG_PROVIDER:                 AWS
FOG_REGION:                   us-west-2
```

**gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

#aws
gem "fog", "~>1.20"
gem 'asset_sync'

group :development do 
    gem 'thin'
end

group :production do 
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

**I also ran:**

```
heroku config:add FOG_PROVIDER=AWS AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy
```

Along with

```
heroku config:add FOG_DIRECTORY=localize
```

And then when I run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Or

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

**I get this output;**

```
rake aborted!
AssetSync::Config::Invalid: Fog directory can't be blank, Aws access key can't be blank, Aws secret access key can't be blank
```

Anyone who has experience with rails, heroku, and S3 who could guide me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldnt config.fog_directory = ENV['localize'] be config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'] ?

Comment: and reading the heroku docs to get VARS on the heroku server you may need to do  heroku config:set FOG_DIRECTORY=localize for example..have you checked if using config:add has actually added the VARS to the heroku server by doing heroku config:get FOG_DIRECTORY or do heroku config to see all VARS that you have uploaded

Comment: @Richlewis Yes, I changed the code to config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'] . I also ran heroku config:add and heroku config:set for FOG_DIRECTORY, FOG_PROVIDER, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. The error I now got is `rake aborted!
AssetSync::Config::Invalid: Aws access key can't be blank, Aws secret access key can't be blank`, so it worked on the FOG but not AWS

Comment: have you actually put config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['MY_ACCESS_KEY'] and
  config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['MY_SECRET_KEY'] in your asset_sync config file?

Comment: @Richlewis yes, I have. I ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, and received a new error, which looks like it has to do with permissions; `rake aborted!
Excon::Errors::Forbidden: Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
excon.error.response`

Comment: shouldnt that be config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] and config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] ??

Comment: @Richlewis yes, I just updated what my asset_sync.rb file looks like. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: ill add a copy of what i normally use

Comment: before i do that though uncomment # config.manifest = true

Comment: and what i normally do is just push your code to heroku and the precompile should take care of itself

Answer (score 0):

Ok looking at your settings there seems to be a few things wrong, Ill add what i normally use and hopefully it will help you

Production.rb

```
ExampleApp::Application.configure do

config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://exampleapp.s3.amazonaws.com"

config.cache_classes = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.serve_static_assets = true

config.assets.compress = true

config.assets.compile = true

config.assets.digest = true

end
```

asset_sync.rb

```
if defined?(AssetSync)
 AssetSync.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = ENV['FOG_PROVIDER']
  config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
  config.fog_region = ENV['FOG_REGION']

 # Don't delete files from the store
 config.existing_remote_files = "delete"

 # Automatically replace files with their equivalent gzip compressed version
 config.gzip_compression = true

# Use the Rails generated 'manifest.yml' file to produce the list of files to
# upload instead of searching the assets directory.
config.manifest = true

config.custom_headers = { '.*' => { cache_control: 'max-age=31536000', expires: 1.year.from_now.httpdate } }
 end
end
```

Comment: No luck :( but thanks for the help. Because this isn't working, do you know if I were to get rid of everything s3 related (gems, initializers, etc) and then precompile assets like before would it go back to normal?

Comment: i really cant see why thats not working, is this the first bucket you have setup with amazon?  have you others that are working? kinda obvious but thought i would check, have you set up billing with them so that they can charge for usage?

Comment: Yes, this is the first time using AWS. I normally just use heroku, but because there are a lot of images, js, and css, it's kind of slow so I wanted to speed it up (heard s3 was how to do that). I signed up for the free tier because this is the only site I have using s3

Comment: yes an S3 bucket will help a lot. what did you name your bucket in S3? is it definitely localize ?

Comment: reason i ask is if you try to go to http://localize.s3.amazonaws.com/ access is denied which tells me that the bucket name is incorrect ?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely localize. I'm looking at the S3 console and it says 'The bucket 'localize' is empty'. When I went to localize.s3.amazonaws.com, I saw `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`

Comment: try deleting that bucket and set it back up again... double check the key and secret also...

Comment: also how are you creating the bucket ? are you trying to set any advanced options, I just name the bucket and select my region then click create

Comment: I will indeed do that, and I'll let you know how it goes. That's how I created it before, but I will delete it and try again.

Comment: well this should work so lets keep going until it does

Comment: I deleted it, and created a new one. I got new security keys (access and secret), ran heroku config:set on them to update, pushed all to master, and when I was waiting for the page to load I briefly saw '..waiting for localize.s3-us-west-2', but then it still didn't work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62404/discussion-on-answer-by-richlewis-asset-sync-not-pushing-to-s3).

Comment: @bluefeet tried to move to chat a long time ago but the OP does not have enough rep to do so, thanks

Comment: @Richlewis No problem, the mods have a bit more power to do this so I took care of it for you. :)